# Highlight on code open and close bracket visual studio 2015

Tags: visual-studio-2015, nuget-package

As I saw one of my colleague pc on the visual studio. Where when mouse point on the closing bracket, that bracket became red and its opening bracket also became red so its highlight each other.

And I have asked to him, he forget the plugin name which he install from nuget manager of visual studio

And I have surfing over google as well as stack over flow but i didn't got it. So if you know that name please help me, because finding blocks of code will became easy.

Thanks Advance.

Answer (score 0):

To achieve similar effect you can use Tools -> Options -> Fonts and Colors -> Brace Matching and set it's colors to red.

[image]

Comment: Thanks, It's working for c# code but not working for javascript bracket